# point A is equal distance away from the Y axis and B point . What will be the value of k?

Tags: geometry

Lets we have a coordinates in the Y axis. Let we have another coordinate  A(5,k) which is equal from the Y axis and a cordinate B [image](2,3).

How to find out the k?

I have evaluated the distance then, 
$$(5-2)^2 + (k-3)^2 = (0-5)^2 + (b-k)^2$$

In this way  have not got the solution.

Comment: Two of us have read your post differently.  Your equation supports my reading, but I see mathlove's reading that $k=b$ so you are measuring the closest distance from A to the Y axis.  Please clarify.  As we are answering different questions, we are getting different answers.

Comment: @user2378 : If it is true what I wrote at the top of my answer, then my answer is what you want. If it is not true, then we cannot decide one $k$ as Ross Millikan says. In other words, we cannot solve it anymore.

Comment: I have edited for more readble. Can you check now please?

Answer (score 4):

If you are saying that

"the distance between $A$ and $y$-axis is the same as the distance between $A$ and $B$,"

then your $b$ has to be $k$ (why?).

So, setting $b=k$, you can find $k$.

**P.S.** You'll get 
$$9+(k-3)^2=25\Rightarrow (k-3)^2=4^2\Rightarrow k-3=\pm 4\Rightarrow k=-1,7.$$

Comment: Y axis and B point are equal distance away from the point A. What will be the value of k?

Comment: I think OP wants the two segments in the drawing to be equal.  This does not require $b=k$, in fact it does not allow it.

Comment: Mathlove, Can you please see the question. I have not got you.

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I think that mathlove solution is correct - the sketch is incorrect.

Comment: @user2378: I understand what you mean. So, I just wrote that "if..." Also, see my comment below at Ross's answer. You can't decide one $k$ because $k$ depends on $b$.

Comment: Your reading is correct-see user2378's last comment to my answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Expand the squares, getting $9+k^2-6k+9=25+b^2-2bk+k^2$

Turn this into a quadratic in $k$, considering $b$ to be a constant

$k^2+(2b-6)k-(7+b^2)=0$

Now apply the quadratic formula

Comment: I understand what you mean, but no $k^2$, right?

Comment: I did this but how to solve the b where as b is not unknown?

Comment: @user2378 : Ross's idea is nice. But I think we can't dicide $k$ because all we can get is $(2b-6)k=7+b^2.$ Since $b\not=3$, we have $$k=\frac{b^2+7}{2b-6}.$$ This means $k$ depends on $b$.

Comment: You will get an equation connecting $k$ and $b$.  You can't go further unless somebody gives you $b$.  You have one equation in two unknowns.  To be specific, if $b=3, k=\pm 4$  if $b=0, k=3\pm \sqrt 2$

Comment: @user2378, is the question goes somewhat like "let $A(5,k)$ be a point such that the distances between the y axis and the point (2,3) to A are equal"?

Comment: point A is equal distance away from the Y axis and B point

Comment: Then as mathlove says, $b=k$ and your figure is incorrect.  The line from A to the Y axis should be horizontal-the shortest distance from a point to a line is perpendicular to the line.

Comment: @user2378: If you understand what Ross says, then you'll know that my answer is what you want.